# Jackson conversion problem with spring boot version 2.2.3 and above

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, java-11

If the data transfer rate is more than 4kb then we are getting the following exception:
(After some limit its throwing an error but when i changed from jetty server to tomcat it works properly)

```
DEBUG c.e.config.ExceptionConfiguration.handleConflict - ExceptionConfiguration: handleConflict
java.lang.IllegalStateException: s=OPEN,api=BLOCKED,sc=false,e=null
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.flush(HttpOutput.java:681)
at org.springframework.session.web.http.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.flush(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:499)
at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.flush(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:520)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.flush(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1153)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:923)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:287)
```

Comment: This seems to be an issue with jetty. https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/4461 check this URL for details. And it has been fixed in latest release i.e https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/releases/tag/jetty-9.4.26.v20200117

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a [bug](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/4461) in  [Eclipse Jetty](http://%20https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/download.html)  which has been fixed in release[9.4.26.v20200117] that can be downloaded using [LINK](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-distribution/9.4.26.v20200117/jetty-distribution-9.4.26.v20200117.zip).

From VERSION.txt

> jetty-9.4.26.v20200117 - 17 January 2020
>
> - 2620 Exception from user endpoint onClose results in unclosed    WebSocketSession
> - 4383 Errors deleting multipart tmp files java.lang.NullPointerException    under heavy load
> - 4444 TLS Connection Timeout Intermittently
> - 4461 IllegalStateException in HttpOutput with Jersey